# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Sendkeys not working. Please help me to resolve this..

```
WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='username']"));      
username.sendKeys("123456");
```

Console:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'

  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.31)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86) 
(WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds

Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'
System info: host: 'NEW-PC', ip: '192.168.0.103', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
```

Driver info:

```
org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286..., userDataDir: C:\Users\NEW\AppData\Local\...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 65.0.3325.31, webStorageEnabled: true}
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

I was seeing the same issue. The problem only appears when using Chrome 65 (currently: dev channel). With Chrome 64 (both stable channel and beta channel) everything worked fine.

It turns out I had an old chromedriver installed. Specifically, I was using `chrome=65.0.3325.51` with `chromedriver=2.29.461585`. Running `npm install -g chromedriver` bumped chromedriver to 2.35.528157 and now the problem is solved.

**TL;DR**: run `npm install -g chromedriver`

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Updated the chrome driver to 2.35

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer solves your problem, it's customary to mark it as "accepted answer".

Comment: chromedriver v2.35 supports chrome 62-64 at the moment

Comment: I updated this to 2.38.0, But when I check the version, it always says 2.33. I have changed the package.config (Visual Studio C#)...I cannot find any reference to 2.33 anymore. Where could this be? I tried to delete the project and recreate it.I am using the standalone selenium server..

Comment: my chromedriver didn't automatically update in katalon studio. why is this and what can I do about it?

Comment: Performed chromedriver update in visual studio with NuGet package Manager and everything works fine as before.

Comment: This solution doesn't work. i have chrome 71 and driver version 2.45

Comment: @NarendraR did you find any solution to this problem? It's been almost 2 days, I can't find the solution

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik, Yes i found. refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53883518/exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error

Comment: @NarendraR Thanks bro..I'll look into this

Comment: I just need to put a new args to force to update the chromedriver because of already existed an version installed. 

npm install -g --force chromedriver

Answer (score 16):

The error says it all :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'

  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.31)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86) 
(WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds

Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'
```

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.33*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.33*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v60-62**

- You are using *chrome=65.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.37*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v64-66**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver* version (*v2.33*) and the *Chrome Browser* version (*v65.0*)

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.37**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v65.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.37 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Answer (score 3):

The latest chrome browser requires corresponding latest chromedriver executable for the tests to run.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same issue and installed the chrome drive. Issue got resolved.

npm install chromedriver --chromedriver_version=LATEST

Answer (score 2):

Changing latest version of ChromDriver worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to update you driver the link for all the chromedriver updates are http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
make sure you chromedriver corresponds to your version of chrome

Answer (score 0):

I simply installed a new version of Katalon Studio and it has worked fine.

Comment: Sorry but this solution (if correct) highly depends on the workflow of the user who posted the question. Introducing a new tool when there's no real need looks like a desperate attempt to solve the issue without really understanding the nature/source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens when chrome and chromedriver are not in sync. Either update both to the latest version or make sure they can work together. After running the following commands it worked for me

```
npm install -g chromedriver --chromedriver-force-download
webdriver-manager update
```