# Katalon Studio: how to change java version used when running tests

Tags: java, browser, katalon-studio

I have this error come up, whenever I try to use the .executeJavascript method in Katalon Studio:

```
fill in maintenance request form FAILED because (of) Unable to execute JavaScript. (Root cause: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: element is not defined
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552518 (183d19265345f54ce39cbb94cf81ba5f15905011),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.4 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z'
System info: host: 'Nikkis-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:ce9:9ff4:b41c:6af1%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.4', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
Driver info: com.kms.katalon.selenium.driver.CChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.38.552518 (183d19265345f5..., userDataDir: /var/folders/fl/d70hxqb520v...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 66.0.3359.181, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 3f8395c7ba99d8ae3ec674ea2312a05f)
```

I think I am getting this error because the java version used is pretty old (seen in the error message): java.version: '1.8.0_102'.

However, even after I downloaded and installed java 1.8.0_172, Katalon Studio still uses the older version of java to run tests. why is this, and how can I change the java version?

Comment: Have you checked `PATH` environment variable? The path to Java installation is specified there.

Comment: sorry i don't know where to find the path to java installation; what do you mean?

Comment: It is something like that: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131. Please check in environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a java version issue.
Try using the stable and correct version of chromedriver.

Refer for an already answered question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48665237/4358787

Comment: I already did this, though. The chrome version is the latest stable version, and so is the chromedriver. But my tests still show this error message.

Comment: What versions of chrome and chromedriver are you using?

Comment: sorry, it's in the error message. I am using chrome=66.0.3359.181 and chromedriver=2.38.552518