# Chrome Version 71.x unknown error: call function result missing 'value'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, e2e-testing

**Please don't mark this question as a duplicate, because the other solution doesn't work for me.**

I'm using Angular `v5.x` and using Protractor for E2E testing. But on running the command.

`ng e2e -s false`

It is throwing an error as

```
 Failed: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

  Stack:
    WebDriverError: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
      (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
        at Object.checkLegacyResponse (F:\Commutatus\yop-v3\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:639:15)
        at parseHttpResponse (F:\Commutatus\yop-v3\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:538:13)
        at client_.send.then.response (F:\Commutatus\yop-v3\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:472:11)
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (F:\Commutatus\yop-v3\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1379:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (F:\Commutatus\yop-v3\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (F:\Commutatus\yop-v3\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)
        at asyncRun (F:\Commutatus\yop-v3\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2820:25)
        at F:\Commutatus\yop-v3\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I've followed [this](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/2631) issue on GitHub, but no luck!!!
I've also install **latest** chrome driver from this link http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads. After unzipping and executing the `.exe` file a console window opens, prompting this message

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.45.615291
>   (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387) on port 9515 Only local
>   connections are allowed.

I've re-run the same command again but not working. I've also checked using
`chromedriver --version` the version of `chromedriver` it is `v2.45`.

**Chrome version - 71.0**
**Chrome drivers version - 2.45**

Comment: The log message that you have share which is before updated chromedriver of after that ?

Comment: @akshaypatil It's after the update

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik did you resolve this issue? I have tried other solutions that are mentioned but it doesn't work for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AlfredoBazoLopez Non of the below solution worked for me. What I did is, I have updated my project from Angular `v5.x` to the latest `v7.x` (at that time).

Comment: Thanks, @YashwardhanPauranik and did this work for you? I cannot do it because I am the QA and not the developer of the project. I am getting mad because non of the solutions provided in internet works for me.
I am testing it in a real device and although I am using chromedriver 84, it seems that it is taking an old version:
 WebDriverError: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.111)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455517

Comment: @AlfredoBazoLopez I totally understand your problem. There is some sort of issue in the WebDriver. I would recommend to ask them to use latest version of Angular for better support.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message, it suggest that call to webdriver(wire protocol) responded empty. I suggest downgrade to your chrome to any stable version below 70 and  compatible chromedrive.

Answer (score 0):

As you share console message :-

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387) on port 9515 Only local connections are allowed.
```

this is information message in console in red color, you can avoid and after this you chrome session means chrome window turn on and if you pass any URL it will redirect to that if you have error after this please share with us because i doesn't seem any problem

Comment: @Akshay Patil. Your language is confusing me. I'm not able to get what you are suggesting

Comment: @DebanjanB Also, the solution you are pointing to, has the last comment that "This solution doesn't work with `v71.x`". Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/48665237/5893995

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik You need to update the question and demonstrate how your question is different from the dup marked question. For the record, the most upvoted answer within the dup marked discussion have **107** upvotes and a detailed explanation within the second most upvoted answer.

Comment: @DebanjanB But that solution not fixing the problem for latest chrome version and that is how this question is a bit different